# HTTPError 403 (Forbidden) with Django and python-social-auth connecting to Google with OAuth2

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api

Using `python-social-auth`, I get a `403: Forbiden` error message after accepting access from google

EDIT: I've recently (2017) had the same error but under a new message: `401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**This answer is outdated as the Google+ API is being deprecated on 3/7/19**

You need to add the [`Google+ API`](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus/overview) to the list of enabled APIs on the Google Developer Console (under `APIs`)

Note: If you want to see the real error message, use the traceback to look at the content of the `response` variable (`response.text`). I use werkzeug for that (`django-extensions` + `python manage.py runserver_plus`).

Comment: You save me a day. I have to enable Google+ API even I just use oauth2.

Comment: I still with a problem like that. When I get 403 for a domain(john@doe.com) and granted for another (doe@john.com). I've already enabled Google+ API on it. Any idea?

Comment: @jpklzm any chance the one still throwing this error was a Google Apps for Education account? (Realize it's been a while since your comment.) E.g., a k12.xx.us or .edu domain. I think that's what I'm seeing, but don't have enough data to confirm. Theory: even with Google+ API enabled, if Google Apps admin has disabled Google+ for their domain users, you get this error. (Or something like that.)

Comment: I just added Google+ API and things started to work :). Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm, hope the docs had mentioned this . Also the correct one is Google + API  . I had accidentally enabled the Google+Domains API and that didnt make it work.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks also. I was using this [python-social-auth tutorial by art and logic](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/), but couldn't get past a 403: Forbidden HTTPError at /complete/google-oauth2/ until enabling Google+ API as above **and waiting for a few minutes for Google to enable it**.

Additionally, I had to place the templates in a template directory and set 
`TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/path/to/psa_test/thirdauth/templates/',)`in settings.py.

Hope this helps someone along the way. All in all, it's taken about 6 hours to figure it out. Not too bad, I'm happy.

Comment: Damn. Thank you. So much. I already did what's necessary but it still wasn't working. All I had to do was wait ~5 minutes, and magic, it was working.

Comment: When in doubt, wait 5 minutes! Gotta love async web propagation.

Answer (score 2):

For me I was using the full-URI scope which is deprecated by Google from Sept 1, 2014, this is mentioned in python-social-auth documentation here

http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/google.html#google-oauth2

> Google is deprecating the full-url scopes from Sept 1, 2014 in favor of Google+ API and the recently introduced shorter scopes names. But python-social-auth already introduced the scopes change at e3525187 which was released at v0.1.24.

However if you don't want to Enable the Google+ API for any reason and want to continue working with the full-uri old scope you need to follow the steps mentioned in the same link:

```
# Google OAuth2 (google-oauth2)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]

# Google+ SignIn (google-plus)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USE_DEPRECATED_API = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_USE_DEPRECATED_API = True
```

This worked for me as I didn't want to enable the Google+ API at this point.